# SectionedListView android error inflating class include

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter

Im trying to create a sectioned listView using [this](http://sunil-android.blogspot.com/2013/08/section-header-listview-in-android.html) tutorial, but im keepeing on getting this error in logCat:

```
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #1: Error inflating class include
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:466)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at com.myapp.adapter.EntryAdapter.getView(EntryAdapter.java:37)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2040)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1244)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1155)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1385)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:676)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:828)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:557)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:4802)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:297)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2111)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:12881)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1064)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4441)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.include
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
06-18 13:26:47.538: E/AndroidRuntime(9294):     ... 33 more
```

Here is what i have in the settings_item_head.xml(this is where the error is)

```
<include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
    layout="@android:layout/preference_category" />
```

and here is my adapter:

```
public class EntryAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    private Context context;
    private ArrayList items;
    private LayoutInflater vi;

    public EntryAdapter(Context context, ArrayList items) {
        super(context, 0, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
        vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View v = convertView;
        final Item i = (Item) items.get(position);
        if (i != null) {
            if (i.isSection()) {
                SectionItem si = (SectionItem) i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.settings_item_head, null);
                v.setOnClickListener(null);
                v.setOnLongClickListener(null);
                v.setLongClickable(false);
                final TextView sectionView = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_item_section_text);
                sectionView.setText(si.getTitle());
            } else {
                EntryItem ei = (EntryItem) i;
                v = vi.inflate(R.layout.settings_item_item, null);
                final TextView title = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_title);
                final TextView subtitle = (TextView) v
                        .findViewById(R.id.list_item_entry_summary);
                if (title != null)
                    title.setText(ei.title);
                if (subtitle != null)
                    subtitle.setText(ei.subtitle);
            }
        }
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am really not sure, but should xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" not be deleted from your include? or is it a standalone include?

Comment: @Opiatefuchs im just following the tutorial :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right xml layout for settings_item_head is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
        layout="@android:layout/preference_category" />

</LinearLayout>
```

That solved my issue, the answer was in the tutorials comment

Answer (score 0):

maybe not a solution, but if Your post is not an copy/paste issue, Your layout.xml is a little bit wrong. You have postet:

```
     <include xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text"
     layout="@android:layout/preference_category" />
```

but, the tutorial looks like this:

```
     <linearlayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
     <include android:id="@+id/list_item_section_text" 
     layout="@android:layout/preference_category">
     </include>
     </linearlayout>
```

So, if Your post of the xml is a part of the same from the tutorial, You have to delete:

```
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

from Your include. This has to be placed inside the LinearLayout. Also, if this was really Your fault, after changing it, clean the project.